# Get multidimensional array from ordered list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple nested list.

```
<ol id="draggable" class="nested-sort">
    <li data-id="1">Lion</li>
    <li data-id="2">Snake</li>
    <li data-id="3">Butterfly
        <ol data-id="3">
            <li data-id="31">Fish</li>
            <li data-id="32">Cat</li>
            <li data-id="33">Monkey</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
    <li data-id="4">Parrot</li>
</ol>
```

I want to get all IDs of the `<li>` as a multidimensional array. Therefore I tried to used jQuery's `.each()`, but that returns only one iteration.

```
$( "#draggable li" ).each(function( index ) {
    console.log( index + ": " + $( this ).text() );
});
```

That results in the following output:

```
0: Lion
1: Snake
2: Butterfly                                                
  Fish
  Cat
  Monkey
3: Fish
4: Cat
5: Monkey
6: Parrot
```

Comment: Can you share the exact result you want?

Comment: Did you mean `$(this).data('id')` instead?

Answer (score 1):

So, start by making your life a little easier, because text() does what it should, i.e. return the element's full content: add a span around the li's titles, as follows:

```
<ol id="draggable" class="nested-sort">
        <li data-id="1"><span>Lion</span></li>
        <li data-id="2"><span>Snake</span></li>
        <li data-id="3"><span>Butterfly</span>
            <ol data-id="3">
                <li data-id="31"><span>Fish</span></li>
                <li data-id="32"><span>Cat</span></li>
                <li data-id="33"><span>Monkey<span></li>
            </ol>
        </li>
        <li data-id="4"><span>Parrot</span></li>
    </ol>
```

Then the code goes as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var res = {};
    parse($("#draggable"), res);
    console.log(res);
});

function parse(obj, result) {
    $("li", obj).each(function(index){
        result[index] = {'libelle': $("span", this).first().text(), 'sub': {}};
        parse($("ol", this), result[index]['sub']);
    });
}
```

Output:

```
{
  "0": {
    "libelle": "Lion",
    "sub": {}
  },
  "1": {
    "libelle": "Snake",
    "sub": {}
  },
  "2": {
    "libelle": "Butterfly",
    "sub": {
      "0": {
        "libelle": "Fish",
        "sub": {}
      },
      "1": {
        "libelle": "Cat",
        "sub": {}
      },
      "2": {
        "libelle": "Monkey",
        "sub": {}
      }
    }
  },
  "3": {
    "libelle": "Fish",
    "sub": {}
  },
  "4": {
    "libelle": "Cat",
    "sub": {}
  },
  "5": {
    "libelle": "Monkey",
    "sub": {}
  },
  "6": {
    "libelle": "Parrot",
    "sub": {}
  }
}
```

HTH

Comment: Wait.. That answer might not be the most brilliant piece of code ever, but it does the job, and it was accepted. How did it get "unaccepted"? Couldn't find the answer in the docs. Please enlighten me.